# What did I do wrong in my functions code, that will not change the "Get New Password" text to "Send It"?

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, password

I am wanting to change the text "Get New Password" to "Send It" on the lost password page. The following code is what I have in my functions.php file, but it is not changing the default "Get New Password" text to "Send It' when I reload and hard-refresh the ./wp-login.php?action=lostpassword page of WordPress.

```
add_action( 'lostpassword_form ', 'wpse17711_lostpassword_form' );
function wpse17711_lostpassword_form()
{
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse17711_gettext' );
}

function wpse17711_gettext( $translation, $text )
{
if ( 'Get New Password' == $text ) {
    return 'Send It';
}
return $translation;
}
```

I can add numbers to the end of the add filter and it still does not change the default text:

`add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse17711_gettext', 10, 1 );`

`add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse17711_gettext', 10, 2 );`

`add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse17711_gettext', 9 );`

What's wrong?

**Update**

As per Jack and Greg here is my final code:

```
add_action( 'lostpassword_form', 'wpse17711_lostpassword_form' );
function wpse17711_lostpassword_form()
{
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse17711_gettext' );
}

function wpse17711_gettext( $translation, $text )
{
if ( 'Get New Password' == $translation ) {
    return 'Send It';
}
return $translation;
}
```

Comment: You should use `if ( 'Get New Password' == $translation ) { ... }` instead.

Comment: As Jack said you should use `$translation` not `$text` in the if statement, and you have a space at the end of `'lostpassword_form '` make sure to delete that space inside quotes.

Comment: And, I knew I had to pay close attention to those extremely powerful tiny details and yet I and my relative still missed it. Thanks for the better eye, Greg36. That made it change "Get New Password" to "Send It" on the lost password page and with `$text`. However, Jack Johansson, I went ahead and changed `$text` to `$translation` as you have advised and updated my other function code (text change on the login page) to reflect the same change, too. I sincerely appreciate you both.